# How to bind a domain for MS Project Server 2010?

Tags: microsoft-project

I've installed MS Project Server 2010 and have to connect via a URL like this one:
http://mysite/pwa/
I want to connect using new domain like that:
http://newsite/. I can use redirection settings on IIS but cannot connect by Project Client. Anyway to do that thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the option to set up the new web application with the desired domain mapping and then use this [TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207296.aspx) to help move the content across?